# Bind thickness of LineGeometry to a Value

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I have put this code together that draws a `Line` from (0,0) to (100,100). I know how to `Bind` the `StrokeThickness` property of a `Line' to some other value, but here the line is drawn using`LineGeometry` which doesn't have that property. How can I bind this to another value (for example to Slider.Value) ?

```
var line = new LineGeometry
{
    StartPoint = new Point(0, 0),
    EndPoint = new Point(100, 100)
};

var geometryGroup = new GeometryGroup();
geometryGroup.Children.Add(line);

var drawing = new GeometryDrawing {Geometry = geometryGroup};
var drawingGroup = new DrawingGroup();
drawingGroup.Children.Add(drawing);

var myPen = new Pen {Thickness = 1, Brush = Brushes.Yellow};
drawing.Pen = myPen;

var myImage = new Image {Stretch = Stretch.None, Margin = new Thickness(10)};

var myDrawingImage = new DrawingImage {Drawing = drawingGroup};
myImage.Source = myDrawingImage;

canvas.Children.Add(myImage);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `LineGeometry` is drawn with the `Pen` object you assign to `GeometryDrawing.Pen`. So just bind to the `Thickness` property of the `Pen` like you binded previously to the `Thickness` of the `Line`.

The difference is that `Pen` does not have the `SetBinding` method, as `Line` does (inherited from `FrameworkElement`). The general way of binding properties of any `DependencyObject` is to use the `BindingOperations.SetBinding` method:

```
// setup binding
var binding = new Binding( ...
// and set it for the property
BindingOperations.SetBinding(pen, Pen.ThicknessProperty, binding);
```

Comment: That's where my problem is I don't know how to bind it.

Comment: OK, I've got your problem. `Pen` does not contain `SetBinding` method, because it does not inherit from `FrameworkElement`, as `Line` does. For binding properties of any `DependencyObject`, you can use the method [`BindingOperations.SetBinding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.data.bindingoperations.setbinding(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thanks baSSiLL, this worked. But it is very slow since I have thousands of lines on my canvas. And when I move the slider it struggles to update all the lines.

Comment: Of course, having many graphics primitives with data binding can cause performance problems. Consider changing your approach to drawing completely. Instead of multiple `Line` or `LineGeometry` objects, use one custom class (based on `FrameworkElement`), implementing the `OnRender` method. Read this article for an inspiration:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/magazine/dd483292.aspx